# Equidistant floated <div> elements containing text break the layout

Tags: css

The following [code](https://codepen.io/SSteven/pen/MRwQVr) is modified from Chris Coyier's article on Equidistant inline-block <div> elements.

It is used to make inline-block <div> elements equidistant, (without the necessity of either flex or grid layout).

The code works just fine.

HTML:

### Equidistant divs - Inline-block method

```
<div class="cardbox">
  <div class="card">
  </div>

  <div class="card">
  </div>

  <div class="card">
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
 .cardbox
  {
    height: 125px;
    text-align: justify;
    border: 10px solid black;
    /* font-size: 0.1px;     IE 9 & 10 don't like font-size: 0; */
    min-width: 600px;
    /*background-color: peachpuff;*/
  }

  .cardbox::after
  {
    display: inline-block;
    content: '';
    width: 100%; 
  }

  .card
  {
    width: 150px;
    height: 125px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid navy;
    background: lightblue;
  }
```

However, [here](https://codepen.io/SSteven/pen/MRwVrL), I have modified the HTML to include text in a <div>. (The first <div> includes the digit "1".) Immediately, the layout breaks:

HTML:

```
<div id="container">
  <div>1</div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</div>
```

Can the technique be used to make inline-block elements containing text equidistant?

If not, how can I make such elements equidistant? (My main interest here is to make text cards equidistant.)

For this exercise, I don't want to use either flex or grid layout, since this snippet would be part of a progressively enhanced webpage.

Comment: Is it possible to insert more html tag inside those main `div` ?

Comment: Yes, but it still breaks.

Comment: Will every div have a text in it ? or there is a possibility some of them will be empty ?

Comment: @Mihai, every div will have text in it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `vertical-align: top` in `card` CSS. I just update your code I hope it'll help you out. Thanks

```css
.cardbox
  {
    height: 125px;
    text-align: justify;
    border: 10px solid black;
    min-width: 600px;
  }

  .cardbox::after {
    display: inline-block;
    content: '';
    width: 100%; 
  }

  .card {
    width: 150px;
    height: 125px;
    display: inline-block;
    border: 1px solid navy;
    background: lightblue;
    vertical-align: top;
  }
```

```html
<div class="cardbox">
  <div class="card">1</div>
  <div class="card"></div>
  <div class="card"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: As i did, i didn't read all the question. He says he doesn't want to use flexbox

Comment: He is asking to avoid this methods: "For this exercise, I don't want to use either flex or grid layout, since this snippet would be part of a progressively enhanced webpage."

Comment: Thank you @MihaiT for clarifications. I just update the description and code snippet. Thanks

Comment: Looks great. Will test for text cards and revert.

Comment: This is the simpler of the 2 techniques posted, so I'm marking it as the right answer. Thanks for all the replies. [Here's](https://codepen.io/SSteven/pen/vMOarx) an example of what I did with this technique - it shows 3 text cards equidistant from each other.

Comment: @SSteven thanks for the feedback, great to see people using SO like you did, and for that you ROCK!

Answer (score 1):

By inserting a secondary `div` inside you primary `div`. We can find a work around by using the `position` property of the `div`'s.

I' am looking to give the secondary `div` an `absolute` position so it doesn't affect the layout.

This tecnic is being use to avoid the use of flex or grid, as specified on the question.

```css
.cardbox {
  height: 125px;
  text-align: justify;
  border: 10px solid black;
  min-width: 600px;
}

.cardbox::after {
  display: inline-block;
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
}

.card {
  width: 150px;
  height: 125px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid navy;
  background: lightblue;
  position: relative;
}

.card--content {
  position: absolute;
  background: tomato;
}
```

```html
<div class="cardbox">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card--content">
      1
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <div class="card--content">
    1234
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <div class="card--content">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

This would be my recomended solution.

```css
.cardbox {
  height: 125px;
  text-align: justify;
  border: 10px solid black;
  min-width: 600px;
}

.cardbox::after {
  display: inline-block;
  content: '';
  width: 100%;
}

.card {
  width: 150px;
  height: 125px;
  display: inline-block;
  border: 1px solid navy;
  background: lightblue;
  position: relative;
}

.card--content {
  position: absolute;
  background: tomato;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="cardbox">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card--content">
      1
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <div class="card--content">
    1234
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card">
    <div class="card--content">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Looks great. I'm testing this for text cards and will revert.

Comment: Awesome, on stand by if you need anything